# Run local code on a Heroku production instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is it possible for me to run something like:

```
RAILS_ENV=production heroku run Item.remove_dupes
```

where the code is local on my machine but it is run on my production Heroku instance? (ie not having pushed code to production via GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Heroku console

```
$ heroku run console
```

Edit

Heroku console will automatically run in production mode

Comment: thx - just to be clear, I'd like to run code that is local (ie not on production and that hasn't been deployed) against my production instance. I am pretty sure running `heroku run ...` basically sends the command to the heroku server and runs it locally there. I'm doubting what I do can be done.

Comment: @timpone perhaps you're after this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

Comment: that's about running locally, I want local code to be run on production. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: well this is why I thought you want to use console. You can execute the code directly against production code. Drawback - you need to write the code in the console. if you want to run rake tasks to clean your database and you need very complex logic that can not be written in the console you may want to connect to production database (although I have never done it with heroku) and execute code locally